# AppEngine HTTPS CName seems to hang

Tags: python, google-app-engine, https, cname

I have setup a CNAME on godaddy for my appengine domain, ie:

store.example.com

If I access via HTTP, it works fine, if however I access it via HTTPS, it seems to partly load and then just hang.
I've notived though if I go direct to the appengine url, ie:

https://example-store.appspot.com - it loads fine.

Is there something I'm missing with my CNAME setup?

Regards

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, nothing's missing, appengine just doesn't support ssl on non-appspot domains [yet](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#httpsapps).  But enabling support for it is at the top of their [todo](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html) list.

Answer (score 2):

App Engine has now launched [SSL for Custom Domains](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl). You can choose from either SNI or VIP based SSL. Wildcard and multi domain certificates are supported which allow you to use your certificates across multiple applications and domains.